# Jquery Не получается суммировать ячейки в выделенных строчках

Tags: javascript, jquery

При клике на строчку, ячейкам присваивается `class="active"`, надо суммировать ячейки в выделенных строчках.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>name1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="total">?</td>
    <td class="total">?</td>
    <td class="total">?</td>
    <td class="total">?</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  $("tr").click(function() {
    $(this).children("td").toggleClass("active");

    var totals=[0,0,0,0];
    $("table").each(function() {
      $(this).find('.active').each(function(i){
        totals[i]+=parseInt( $(this).text());
      });
    });

    $("td.total").each(function(i){
      $(this).html(totals[i]);
    });

 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы ищите элементы `.active` для таблицы и они нумеруются сплошняком 1, 2, 3, ..., 10, 11, 12. В результате у вас в `totals` не 4 элемента, а 12 (3 столбца на 4 элемента в них).

Вам нужно вместо

```
$("table").each(function() {
```

Записать

```
$("table tr").each(function() {
```

Тогда у вас нумерация будет в пределах каждой строки таблицы.

Comment: заработало, но я не понял почему 9?

Comment: @YarNik Потому что вы считаете количество элементов .active у таблицы table - таких элементов у таблицы 9 штук по 3 элемента в каждой строке. Когда вы считаете количество элементов .active у строки - их оказывается по 3 в каждой строке.

Comment: по 4 в строчке.

Comment: Да, по правильно, по 4 в строчке, сейчас поправлю ответ.

Comment: я суть уловил, спасибо! сбила цифра 9 =)